# SPI protocol master CS pulled low

Tags: spi, embedded, hardware

If I run the system on SPI protocol and keep the master slave connected with it, will communication happen if I disconnect both the CS pins master and slave and tie them to ground?

Comment: This can't be answered until you explain a lot more about your situation.  What the master and save *are* would be a good addition, to start.

Answer (score 2):

CS is the only signal in the SPI protocol that is guaranteed to keep the master and slave state machines synchronized. Synchronized in the sense that most slaves require knowledge about where the byte boundaries are, and some slaves treat the first byte(s) of each transfer specially.

If your system starts up cleanly and operates free of glitches and other upsets, you might get away without using CS when you have only a single slave. But if some event causes the slave to "see" a different number of clock cycles than the master, they will be forever out of sync -- until the next system restart.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, because CS is an output from master, and there will be a short circuit if master pulls it high.

And most communication on SPI bus is not a continuous stream, but transactions that start and end. Transactions on bus may require that transactions are delimited by CS returning high after a transfer to complete the transaction and to start a new transaction when CS goes low.

If there is even a single glitch in the clock signal, doubling a pulse or missing a pulse, it will skew the whole transaction by one bit.

So if your data is stream based and your chips are both MCUs that can work without CS toggling, and there never happens an single glitch on the clock, then it is possible to work without CS and tying it low on the slave. Some MCUs as master can do anything it wants such as leave it high, and some MCUs as slaves can be configured to ignore CS.